# Passing "event" in Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

There are more than couple of questions here already explaining that there is no window.event in FF and that you'd have to pass it as argument and that's all fine. I also found out that you have to pass *event* to get this working as follows. But how do I achieve the same in Knockout?

```
<input type="button" value="TestPlain" onClick="test(event)"/>
```

I tried the following code with Knockout data-binding on click event.

```
<input type="button" value="TestKO" data-bind="click: function(){ test(event) }"/>
```

I also tried passing *window.event* on the argument but to no avail.

It keeps throwing me with the error:-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null
```

Here's my jsfiddle for the attempt. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ybwfe/

Comment: In your fiddle your problem is that you are calling `ko.applyBindings` before the DOM has been loaded... http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/qArv7/ So was this just a problem in your fiddle?

Comment: You are partly right. It was not working on fiddle with the way I had loaded my library. I have corrected the loading issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/YbwFe/
Also, thanks to @Micheal Best for helping me find the event object in Knockout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout provides the event as the second argument to the function:

```
<input type="button" data-bind="click: function(data, event){ test(event) }"/>
```

Reference: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note_2_accessing_the_event_object_or_passing_more_parameters